# ¿Cómo obtener un listado de productos de Ebay haciendo uso de su API y PHP?

Tags: php, api, php7, ebay-api

**¿Qué necesito?**

Buscar productos en Ebay haciendo uso de su API, puede ser a través de su EAN (Código único europeo) o palabras claves (marca y modelo).

**¿Qué utilizo?**

PHP 7.2

**¿Leí la documentación?**

Llevo días leyendo y no puedo hacerlo funcionar, según la documentación la última vez que se actualizó fue en el año 2010.

[Guía del usuario - EBAY API](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/concepts/findingapiguide.html#useproduct)

[Haciendo una llamada a la API](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/Concepts/MakingACall.html#syntax)

[findItemsByProduct - EBAY API](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByProduct.html#Samples): Esto es lo debo usar en primera instancia para intentar encontrar el producto con su EAN, en caso de que falle, intentaría con este:

[Búsqueda por palabras claves](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/concepts/findingapiguide.html#usekeywords)

**¿Qué tengo hecho?**

Por el momento estoy intentando hacer funcionar la petición **findItemsByProduct** con el siguiente código:

```
    $r = 
    "http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?".
   "OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&".
    "SERVICE-VERSION=1.9.0&".
    "SECURITY-APPNAME=MI-KEY-API&".
    "RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&".
    "REST-PAYLOAD&".
    "GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&".
    "paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2&".
    "productId.@Type=ReferenceID&".
    "productId=183810050014";

print_r(file_get_contents($r));
```

**¿Qué error te aparece?**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><findItemsByProductResponse xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"><ack>Failure</ack><errorMessage><error><errorId>4</errorId><domain>Marketplace</domain><severity>Error</severity><category>Request</category><message>Product ID is required.</message><subdomain>Search</subdomain></error></errorMessage><version>1.13.0</version><timestamp>2019-05-17T09:17:10.109Z</timestamp></findItemsByProductResponse>
```

**¿Verificaste que estás enviando el "Product ID"?**

Así es:

```
http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&SERVICE-VERSION=1.9.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=my-api&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=2&productId.@Type=ReferenceID&productId=183810050014
```

**¿Me podrían ayudar a encontrar el problema?**

Aclaraciones:

- He omitido colocar mi key api, pero aparece en la url de muestra que dejé el punto anterior.
- He reemplazado "ReferenceID" por "EAN" y el número de referencia por un EAN cualquiera y el error es el mismo.
- ¿Hay alguna versión superior a la 1.9? he puesto la última que la documentación dice.
- Estoy usando sandbox, y si, la api key es para sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce porque `@type` se escribe en minúsculas y el productId no es válido. Prueba con **53039031**, es un id que viene en la documentación del api.

```
"productId.@type=ReferenceID&".
```

Comment: Hola, al final he pasado de usar "findItemsByProduct" ya que así lo recomiendan en algunos post de stackoverflow en inglés y en el foro oficial de la API. Lo que ellos recomiendan es usar la "FindAdvanced**" y poner el EAN en la keywords

Comment: Si quieres edita tu respuesta, basandote en esto: https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/13801/finditemsbyproduct-using-ean-codes-always-fails-bu.html (que fue lo que solucionó el problema) y la marcaré como util y solución del problema